# Проблема с ключами и индексами после восстановления таблиц oracle из recycle

Tags: oracle

Всем привет. Такая проблема. В производственной базе случайным образом были удалены таблицы. После восстановления их из Recycle bin в них поменялись имена ключей и индексов на имена вот в таком духе - BIN$6z/8GvE6RfC0zfcxK6kTlQ==$0. Не могу понять как вернуть все как было. Переименовать вручную не получается, удалить тоже. При попытке переименовать ошибка

ORA-01735:invalid ALTER TABLE option
--Drop primary, uniqu and foreign key constraints alter table AB
drop constraint BIN$6z/8GvE6RfC0zfcxK6kTlQ==$0 cascade

База - Oracle 11.2.0.3.0, в качестве среды разработки используется PL/SQL Developer 10.0.0.1686

Answer (score 0):

Ответ получил на сайте cyberforum от Grossmeister:

> А если имя в двойные кавычки?

Написал 
ALTER TABLE MONITOR DROP CONSTRAINT "BIN$6z/8GvE6RfC0zfcxK6kTlQ==$0==$0"
и все получилось!

Я просто переименовывал в PL/SQL Developer через графический интерфейс, а не писал запрос. Видимо когда Девелопер делает переименование, кавычки не подставляются и поэтому выходит ошибка.